# Tool to Generate 2D Data via Mouse Clicking

Tags: data, tools

Often when I am learning new machine learning methods or experimenting with a data analysis algorithm I need to generate a series of 2D points. Teachers also do this often when making a lesson or tutorial.

In some cases I just create a function, add some noise, and plot it, but there are many times when I wish I could just click my mouse on a graph to generate points. For instance, when I want to generate a fairly complex relationship between x and y, it's a hassle to think of the right formulation to generate the points programmatically.

Does there exist a tool that will allow me to generate data points using my mouse, with an option to export to CSV (or other simple format)?

For example, I am currently learning how to use mutual information and entropy as a metric of dependence between variables. I'd like to see what happens when I have data that is clearly dependent but does not have a linear relationship, so I drew this image:

[image: Non-linear dependence]

Now I just need a way to export the coordinates of the points to CSV. I realize this is a simple program and I could write my own, but surely someone has already done this and created a tool to do so? It could be a website, an .exe, Python source, or any other application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://drawdata.xyz/

I think this one also good, the highest vote one, you have to click one by one to generate more data points, this one is much faster...

[image]

Comment: I like how fast it is to draw many points. One downside: can't draw single points if you wanted.

Answer (score 9):

I recently discovered this site: https://guoguibing.github.io/librec/datagen.html

Outputs list of points, and color ID (class) for each point.

**Screenshot:**
[image: Datagen screenshot]

Comment: In Python, one can convert the output from this website to a Pandas Dataframe using `points = pandas.read_csv(io.BytesIO(pointsTxt), sep='\n', delimiter=',', names=['x','y','class'])`

Comment: Sadly, this website is no longer online :(

Comment: ...but I found a working link and have updated the link above.

Answer (score 3):

In R:

First set up a blank plot with whatever x and y scale limits you need:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(11,20),ylim=c(10,99))
```

Then click click click with mouse-button 1 and end with mouse-button 2 (probably):

```
pts = data.frame(locator(type="p"))
```

Then save as a CSV file:

```
write.csv(pts,"pts.csv",row.names=FALSE)
```

producing:

```
"x","y"
20.9461142167608,54.0921852908633
11.6463003491398,24.5409354249845
14.4239385175408,44.1769632963908
14.7755382856928,29.5957544809901
14.7931182741004,62.8409105801038
```

Comment: Still need a way to add classes

Answer (score 0):

I found a simple Python solution, adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/q/25521120/1265192

This also works in a Jupyter Notebook, if desired.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib qt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.set_xlim(0,800)
ax.set_ylim(0,600)

plt.grid(True)

coords = []

def onclick(event):
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    
    print(f'{x:0.1f},{y:0.1f}')

    global coords
    coords.append((x, y))

    ax.scatter([x], [y], c='b', s=150)
    plt.draw()
    
cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)

fig.show()
```

The coordinates are stored in `coords` and also printed to the screen (but with 1 decimal place). One could save the coordinates to a file, but I just copy/paste the printed coordinates wherever I want them.

Answer (score 0):

Just updating the other answers.

You could use this site:
https://guoguibing.github.io/librec/datagen.html

to make it a dataframe:

```
points = pd.read_csv('/content/pontos.csv', sep='\n', delimiter=',', names=['x','y','class'])
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting! However, one of the other answers already suggested this tool. Oh! But I see you found a URL that works, whereas the other answer has a broken link. We can edit that answer with the new link.